# USB-C Wireless transmitter and receiver for file transfer?

Tags: wireless, usb-c

I'm familiar with USB-C wireless transmitters/receivers for video/audio transfer, but are there any designed specifically for file transfer? I'm looking to connect one to an external hard drive, allowing me mobility with my laptop around my apartment while the drive rests on my console. Do such devices exist? Any recommendations or insights would be greatly appreciated.

For context, I work with large-format graphic design files in programs such as InDesign, which require the files to be linked. It's getting to be too much for my internal HD, so I was hoping for something fast enough that I could continue to work on it as it is stored remotely.

Comment: Why would you want this USB-C adapter instead of a network storage device and just using WiFi to access it?

Comment: @Romen any recommendations of one that won't require browser access and behaves as a mounted drive? As far as I've seen, most grant access via browser. For the purposes of my workflow, I'd require a constant sync between the drive and my work files.

Comment: I don't think you're looking at the right thing or are missing a major feature if you're not seeing ones that look like drives in explorer. Windows explorer allows you to connect a network drive like a drive letter on your system if you really need that. Almost all NAS systems allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment referencing a constant synchronization between the remote drive and your work files suggests that a software solution may serve your requirements. I use [Allway Sync](https://allwaysync.com/) which supports network shared drives, NAS systems, etc and the configuration of a given backup plan allows for live/dynamic/instant synchronization, barring open file conflicts, although I believe that one can override that limitation as well.

I'm aware there are other sychronizing programs on the market, but uncertain of the flexibility of configuration. Some are free and Allway Sync has a free trial with limitations. The cost of the Pro version isn't presenting itself on the linked site. I believe that I paid US$20, although it was so long ago, I would expect the price to have risen.